# how to load php page in a div using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Imagine that I have two divs , left div and right div ,

In the left div I have some button. When I click on the home button the page home.php loaded in the right div, I use load() function to do this and when I click on about button the page about.php loaded in the right div .

My problem is that I have some other buttons in that page (I mean about.php). When I click on it some other pages must load in the right div.

I mean when I click on about button in the left div, `about.php` loaded in the right div.

I don't have a problem doing this it's work fine , but the problem is when i click on a button in `about.php`, I want about.php to be hide and load `x.php` in his place (right div).

This is the code that I have :

```
$('#about').click(function () {
   $('#rightdiv').load('about.php', function() {
      $('#about_button').click(function () {
          $('#rightdiv').load('x.php');
      })
   })
})
```

Comment: Any console errors? What else have you tried? What comes back when you debug it?

Comment: @Fossn noting is coming back , about.php doesn't hide and the x.php doesn't loaded, i mean noting happen when i click the button

Comment: Time to read up about event delegation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't nest your click handlers like you have done - they should be separate. Second, when you load the about.php jQuery is unaware of the new stuff that you have placed in the DOM. To fix that you use event delegation, meaning the click event from about.php will bubble up to an element that already existed at the time the page was loaded. jQuery is aware of that element and will handle the event properly.

```
$('#about').click(function () {
   $('#rightdiv').load('about.php');
});

// 'click' event delegated to 'body'
$('body').on('click', '#about_button', function () { // #about_button is in about.php
   $('#rightdiv').load('x.php');
})
```

Comment: Two different evenhandlers doing the exact same thing? Thats not good practice, someone with your rep should do better

Comment: They're not doing the same thing. The OP had nested handlers which would not work. The first handler deals with events in the original document, the second deals with those loaded into the DOM via the AJAX call. Having said that, you could wrap them all into one giant handler, but for the OP I wanted to make sure the concept and direction were clear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the event to the items on load, you tell the browser to check ther `a.nav`'s which occur in the `document`.

```
<a class="nav" href="about.php">about.php</a>
<a class="nav" href="other.php">other.php</a>
<a class="nav" href="last.php">last.php</a>

$(document).on('click', 'a.nav',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = this.href;
    $('#rightdiv').load(page);
})
```

It's better to make the first selecttor ( `$(document)` ) as close to the actual elements, and highly recommended you use an ID:

```
$('#rightdiv').on('click', 'a.nav',function (e) {});
```

In this snippet, all `a.nav` in `#rightdiv` will get triggered, initial load or dynamicly.

Comment: Where is the part about loading `x.php` when clicking on a button in the newly-loaded DIV?

Comment: Missed that, topic isn't the clearest I've encountered

Comment: you didn't understand my problem , my problem is not to load simple page , my problem is that i have a button  inside about.php and when i click on it i want about.php to disappear and load x.php in his place

Comment: All pages with the `.nav` class will be loaded in `#rightdiv` in my example. See the last line of my post.

Answer (score -1):

you have to bind all click events after you load that php page, so create a function, that will do it after every .load call

Comment: Oh please dont :) that would be confusing and very difficult to maintain. If you use `.on()` the right way, this poses no problem, and no need to create functions to re-bind all events (which can create a lot of problems, like all actions happening double!)

Comment: Isn't that what the `.load` callback is for? He's already doing that.

Comment: I think he means that áfter the `load()` you call a function to re-bind all events

Comment: can anyone have the answer please .